# android default Back button minimizes the application after I implement code for action bar back button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, back-button

I have implemented code for action bar button and it works fine but after that my smart phone back button is closes or minimizes when I press it. Here is my Code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

    /**
     * Action Bar Back Button
     */
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
         // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
         case android.R.id.home:
         NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
         return true;
      }
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
      moveTaskToBack(true); 
      AboutActivity.this.finish();
   }
```

Comment: AboutActivity.this.finish(); you are finishing the activity on back button click

Comment: I have tried by removing this code as well but still the same problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void onBackPressed() {
  moveTaskToBack(true); 
  AboutActivity.this.finish();// you are finishing the activity
}
```

if you want to go back try this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // code here to show dialog
     super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
}
```